# ving trouble with multiplication in python

Tags: python

i was recently practicing with python when i came across a slight issue with multiplication every time i run this:

```
nights = raw_input('How many nights do you intend to stay?:')    
if len(nights) > 0 and nights.isdigit():         
    cost = 3000 * nights  
    print cost  
else:  
    print "Error, enter a number"
```

i get this answer once i input, for example 5:

```
How many nights do you intend to stay?:5
55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 (basically very many fives)
```

anyone with any idea on how to solve it.
thanks.

Comment: `int(raw_input('How many nights do you intend to stay?:')  )`, you should also use a try/except to cast

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, This could throw ValueError depending on the user's input. And he is already validating the input in an if statement.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha,  that is why I said to use a try except, isdigit is not how to verify user input

Comment: I completely agree, sorry I didnt read full and missed your statement about try/except.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha, no worries, the OP should probably wrap the code in a while loop too so they can ask again if the input is inavlid

Comment: I agree, that is most important, while printing an appropriate error message.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, *raw_input* returns a string object, and thats why you already have to check for *isdigit*. So, you will need to typecast nights to int first.

Change your code to following -

```
cost = 3000 * int(nights)
```

You are still not getting an error and a valid result because Python supports string multiplication, i.e.,

```
>>> s = 'a'
>>> s * 10
'aaaaaaaaaa'
```